# Behat error: MinkExtension 1.3 only supports Goutte 1.x for MinkGoutteDriver, not Goutte 2.x

Tags: behat, mink, goutte

I've been going round in circles, so I'll start with where I started:

I'm running behat with the following:

`composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "behat/behat": "2.5.*@stable",
        "behat/symfony2-extension": "@stable",
        "behat/mink": "@stable",
        "behat/mink-extension": "@stable",
        "behat/mink-browserkit-driver": "@stable",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "1.*@stable",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "@stable",
        "phpunit/php-code-coverage": "@stable",
        "phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects": "@stable",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "@stable",
        },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin/"
    }
}
```

`behat.yml`:

```
default:
  extensions:
      Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            goutte: ~
            selenium2: ~
```

which gives me this error:

> [RuntimeException]
>
> MinkExtension 1.3 only supports Goutte 1.x for MinkGoutteDriver, not Goutte 2.x.

I need to use behat 2.5.* but other than that, I don't care. How can I get it working?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Ugh.. so obvious.

Add this to the requirements in `composer.json`:

```
        "fabpot/goutte": "1.*@stable",
```

(I thought composer would have realised it needed goutte 1.* but obviously not)

Comment: I suggest to upgrade minkextension from composer.json